Netilas yadayim after anaesthesia
Does waking up after anaesthesia require netilas yadayim? It's not a sleep per, se - but on the other hand, it absolutely is, and perhaps even more so.

In what way is it not sleep?

Ask the question about older people who sleep only in short spurts of 1-2 hours each.

@shmosel. No dreaming.
